# Update all field values by concatenate from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables:

```
  Table items            Table buffer
---------------         -------------
id     keywords         id      value
1      val1             1       val2
2      val1             2       val2
3      val1             3       val2
```

Both keywords and value are VARCHAR(250). Now I want to update all keywords in table ***items*** like this:

```
   Table items
-----------------
id     keywords
1      val1, val2
2      val1, val2
3      val1, val2
```

I tried to achieve this with CONCAT but obviously I'm doing something wrong. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `UPDATE` with `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE items i
INNER JOIN buffer b ON i.id = b.id
SET i.keywords = CONCAT(i.keywords, ', ', b.value);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0878d/1)

Comment: I like your `CREATE`/`INSERT` indentation scheme.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Actually it isn't mine it is generate automatically from the button `Text to DDL` try it yourself :(.

Comment: @Mahmoud: Oh, well, in that case, I don't like your `CREATE`/`INSERT` indentation scheme :P

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way as well:

```
UPDATE items, buffer 
SET items.keywords = CONCAT(items.keywords, buffer.value) 
where items.id = buffer.id;
```